# When will I not see questions tagged as ignored anymore?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I really like the "Ignored Tags" function on Stack Overflow, and the fact that questions marked as ignored seem invisible to me (It really reduces the noise level a lot).

However on ServerFault the ignored questions are only dimmed/light gray and still visible.  How much rep do I need for this to work?

---

Thanks devinb, that "Hide Ignored Tags" solved it.

Comment: It's not about points, you just need to tweak your user prefs; see devinb's answer.

Comment: My pleasure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Click on your name at the top of the screen
2. Click on the "Prefs" tab
3. Check off "Hide Ignored Tags"